# Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, azure-aks

I am trying to do blue green deployments for AKS using Jenkins. I am currently following this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-to-aks-using-blue-green-deployment-pattern

When I run the pipeline I am getting the following error:

kubectl --kubeconfig=kubeconfig delete deployment todoapp-deployment-blue
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "todoapp-deployment-blue" not found
What exactly does this error mean and how do I resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

This error means that there is no deployment called `todoapp-deployment-blue` in your kubernetes namespace and you need to create it first (to delete it, lol).